# What does "(test1, test2, test3="3", test4="4", test5 = "5", test6 = "6")" do?

Tags: ruby

This question is based off some really odd code I recently found in a colleagues work. He claims not to know how it works only he copied it from somewhere else. That's not good enough for me, I want to understand what's going on here.

If we have something like:

```
(test1, test2, test3="3", test4="4")
```

The result will be that `test1 == "3"`, `test2 == "4"`, `test3 == nil` and `test4 == "4"`.
I understand why this happens, but if we do something like:

```
(test1, test2, test3="3", test4="4", test5 = "5", test6 = "6")
```

now the result is `test1 == "3"`, `test2 == "4"`, `test3 == "5"`, `test4 == "4"`, `test5 == "5"`, `test6 == "6"`.

Why isn't `test5 == nil`?

Comment: for the curious, could you explain why the first assignments do what they do?  that's a surprise to me!  =)

Comment: @maerics: it's parsed as `test1, test2, test3 = ("3", test4="4")`.

Comment: I just noticed, I'm getting a different result for `test4`. You're getting `6` but I'm getting `4`, with your code.

Comment: Yeah, typo, edited for correct results

Comment: Hmmm... software developers pasting code from a website with no idea what it does as long as it appears to work.  He should be fired.

Comment: @Jörg: thanks, and wow, this is one of few examples where Matz's idea of "least surprise" is very different from mine!

Comment: @maerics: What would *you* have expected? Would you have expected assignment to be left-associative? Why? Assignment is almost always right-associative, see for example http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Right-associativity_of_assignment_operators

Comment: @Jörg: actually it was the parsing that surprised me, I would have expected it to be equivalent to `t1, t2, t3, t4 = "3", "4"`, the rvalue `t4="4"` is mysterious to me.

Comment: @Ed, if it were up to me he would be.

Comment: Good homework trolling.  A++++, would assist this student again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's executing like this:

```
(test1, test2, test3) = ("3"), (test4 = "4"), (test5 = "5"), (test6 = "6")

# Equivalent:
test1 = "3"
test2 = test4 = "4"
test3 = test5 = "5"
      ; test6 = "6"
```

Comment: No, I don't think so. If that was the case test2 would be nil, but it's 4, as you'd expect.

Comment: nope, I tested my code, after running the above line I get 3 4 5 4 5 6 as values.

Comment: Actually, my apologies Jeremy, you're completely right. Thanks, it's a confusing way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

An assignment statement returns the RHS (right hand side of the expression), which is how `a = b = 4` sets both `a` and `b` to 4:

```
a = b = 4
-> a = (b = 4) // Has the "side effect" of setting b to 4
-> a = 4       // a is now set to the result of (b = 4)
```

Keeping this in mind, as well as the fact that Ruby allows for multiple assignments in one statement, your statement can be rewritten (Ruby sees commas and an equals sign, and thinks that you're trying to do multiple assignments, with the first equals splitting the LHS (left hand side) and RHS):

```
test1, test2, test3="3", test4="4", test5 = "5", test6 = "6"
-> test1, test2, test3 = "3", (test4 = "4"), (test5 = "5"), (test6 = "6")
```

The RHS is evaluated first, which leaves us with:

```
test1, test2, test3 = "3", "4", "5", "6"
```

with the side effect of setting `test4` to `"4"`, `test5` to `"5"`, and `test6` to `"6"`.

Then the LHS is evaluated, and can be rewritten as:

```
test1 = "3"
test2 = "4"
test3 = "5"
// since there are 3 items on the LHS and 4 on the RHS, nothing is assigned to "6"
```

So at the end of the statement, six variables will have been set:

```
test1 == "3"
test2 == "4"
test3 == "5"
test4 == "4"
test5 == "5"
test6 == "6"
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run your second example:

```
(test1, test2, test3="3", test4="4", test5 = "5", test6 = "6")
```

I get a different result from what you report:

```
test1=="3", test2=="4", test3=="5", test4=="4", test5=="5", test6=="6"
```

(note that test4 is "4", not "6")

Which makes sense to me, because it parses like this:

```
((test1, test2, test3) = ("3", (test4="4", (test5 = "5", (test6 = "6")))))
```

So you get an evaluation something like this:

```
((test1, test2, test3) = ("3", (test4="4", (test5 = "5", (test6 = "6")))))
[assign "6" to test6]
((test1, test2, test3) = ("3", (test4="4", (test5 = "5", "6"))))
[assign "5" to test5]
((test1, test2, test3) = ("3", (test4="4", "5", "6")))
[assign "4" to test4]
((test1, test2, test3) = ("3", "4", "5", "6"))
[assign "3", "4", and "5" to test1, test2, and test3 respectively]
```

Comment: Edited so that the original question shows the correct values